# Application gets hanged on pressing back button when video is buffering in video view

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am playing video on video view, the issue which i am facing is that when user press back button, the application gets stuck for some time and then onStop method is called of that activity, i don't know why the application is taking time in calling onStop method. Please can anyone help me out.

Comment: You need to stop video from play mode bcz it will continue to play video in background.

Comment: i have stop the video from play mode, but still i am facing the same issue, i.e the first activity gets displayed immediately on pressing back button but the control gets on it after some time.

Answer (score 0):

What jaydroider said is right. You have to override onBackPressed method as follows

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    <stop your video here>
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

It is important that you stop the video before calling super.onBackPressed(); so that your application does not get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop video on `onPause()` not on `onBackPressed()`. Because user may use the `Home` key while using your app. This will stop playing video whenever your screen is not visible to user.

Comment: The main issue which i am facing is that  the first activity gets visible onBackPressed but the control to that activity comes after some time, and when i perform any event on first activity the app gets crashed as control is coming late.

Comment: Check this `onPause()` gets called when you go back or whenever first  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#CoordinatingActivities